Salesforce API Error: CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT for ValidationRule
I'm encountering an issue modifying a Salesforce Validation Rule via the API. My attempt to update the rule with the ID '03dDn000001evPOIAY' results in the error message:

"Cannot modify managed object: entity=ValidationFormula,
component=03dDn000001evPO, field=FieldEnumOrId, state=installed:
newValue='null', oldValue='00NDn00000YwUYt'", with errorCode
'CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT'.

Here's my code snippet
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

try:
    # Establish Salesforce connection
    sf = Salesforce(username='***********', password='********', security_token='********')

    # Query using the Tooling API to get the validation rule
    tooling_query = ("SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, ValidationName, Active "
                     "FROM ValidationRule WHERE ValidationName = 'Require_Default_Consignor'")
    response = sf.restful('tooling/query', params={'q': tooling_query})

    # Check if the query returned any records
    if response['records']:
        record = response['records'][0]
        validation_rule_id = record['Id']
        print("Connection successful. Retrieved validation rule:")
        print(f"ID: {validation_rule_id}")
        print(f"Created Date: {record['CreatedDate']}")
        print(f"Validation Name: {record['ValidationName']}")
        print(f"Active: {record['Active']}")

        # Prepare the metadata for update
        metadata = {
            "description": "Updated via Python Script",  # Include your desired description here
            "active": True,  # Set the active state
            "errorConditionFormula": "NOT(ISNULL(ValidationName))",
            "errorMessage": "Error updating somecolumn."
        }

        # Update the Validation Rule using PATCH method with the metadata
        update_response = sf.restful(f'tooling/sobjects/ValidationRule/{validation_rule_id}',
                                     method='PATCH', json={'Metadata': metadata})

        print("Validation rule updated successfully.")
    else:
        print("Connection successful but no validation rules found.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred:", e)

Any guidance on resolving this CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT error would be greatly appreciated.

It appears that this validation rule is part of a managed package. If so, you cannot change most aspects of the validation rule, whether through the API or through the UI. When trying to update a validation rule, you are only permitted to change the Active status for that validation rule. See this document.

The one thing you can do with such validation rules is disable them (or re-enable). Find the details here.

@PhilW You're right, of course. I was mostly focused on the formula. I'll edit to clarify.

Thank you for the clarification. Does this mean I can't disable or enable managed validation rules via the API as I tried above? If so, how can I do that? Any advice?

@vw96 It seems you can only change this state either through the metadata API or the UI. I tried this in the Tooling API, and it required the formula to be passed in, yet trying to do so would result in an error.

Updating via metadata API worked, Thank you !
